# Sending an email from a specific account using Outlook and Delphi

Tags: delphi, outlook

I need to be able to use a specific sender address when I send emails from Delphi using Outlook automation.
I have the code running now, but it uses the default account in Outlook and I need to be able to specify another.
How can this be done?

I have done it in VBA so it should be possible in Delphi also.

Comment: If you have it working in VBA, then you know what you need to do and have left something out of your Delphi implementation. Probably where you logon to the MAPI namespace using the email/user and/or password of the specific account you want to use. Without some code (preferably both VBA and Delphi) we are all stabbing in the dark here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems are likely to be with enumerating/indexing the accounts collection, which is slightly less convenient from Delphi then what you are used to in VBA.

I'll post some example code below. For brevity and pastability, I've used OleVariants, and declared olMailItem locally. In production code, make sure to use early binding in stead.

Also, good look dodging all the security warnings Outlook throws when automating it like this.

```
const
  olMailItem = 0;

var
  application: OleVariant;
  mailItem: OleVariant;

begin
  application := getActiveOleObject( 'Outlook.Application' );

  mailItem := application.createItem( olMailItem );

  mailItem.recipients.add( 'someone@somewhere.com' );
  mailItem.subject := 'This is a subject';
  mailItem.body := 'StackOverflow... the best time to hang out at christmas.';

  // This line allows you to pick any account by name
  mailItem.sendUsingAccount := application.session.accounts.item( 'some account' );

  mailItem.send;
end;
```

Comment: Result := 'Invalid variant operation'

Comment: At what line? What did the debugger tell you? Did you replace the account name with one that actually exists? Was Outlook started when you run it? Are you running Outlook 2007+? If you want help, please provide more info. The code I posted is trivial and tested, so please work on the assumption you are not telling us something important.

Comment: For some strange reason the code
if Outlook.Session.Accounts.Item(i) = aSender then
is the provider of this error
I changed it to         
AccountCurrent := Outlook.Session.Accounts.Item(i);
if AccountCurrent = aSender then
where AccountCurrent is a string
I sound very strange, but it is the only thing I have changed and now the code works.
The check is needed to be sure that a valid account is selected - else I get another error.